# Nombre de columna invalido al escribir una consulta en Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

Estoy escribiendo mis primeras consultas en Transact SQL utilizando Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 y no logro entender el motivo por el cual el administrador de base de datos me marca `invalid column name` y le más subraya en color rojo

¿A qué se debe esto?

```sql
SELECT 
    a.model_name, 
    COUNT(a.model_name) as TotalDeActivos, 
    a.price as PrecioPorUniudad,
    SUM(a.price) AS PrecioTotal
FROM 
    Asset as a
GROUP BY 
    a.model_name, a.price
ORDER BY 
    TotalDeActivos ASC
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el código funciona correctamente, es probable que no se haya refrescado el caché local que tiene toda la información de los objetos disponibles. Para solucionarlo, puedes ir al menu Edición -> Intellisense -> Refrescar caché local. O puedes usar el método abreviado del teclado Ctrl+Shift+R

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]